How to Run a Python ETL Script in Azure Data Factory and Choose the Best Approach?
I'm currently working on an ETL process where I need to run a Python script within Azure Data Factory (ADF). The script involves data extraction, transformation, and loading (ETL) tasks. I’m aware that ADF supports various ways to execute custom code, but I’m unsure about the best approach to run my Python script efficiently.
Could someone help me understand the different approaches to run a Python ETL script in ADF? Additionally, what factors should I consider when choosing the best approach for my specific use case?

ADF by itself has no activity to run Python scripts directly. So you have the following options:

Azure function - create an Azure function with your code, and use ADF to run it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity
Azure Databricks - create an Azure Databricks workspace, and put your python code in a notebook or as a Python file. Run that notebook with an Azure Databricks activity in ADF - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-python or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-notebook .

Personally, I'd prefer the Databricks option, since it also give you an environment to develop and test your code conveniently. But you should be aware that all options require additional charges for the services you use.

I am looking for guidance on the cost implications of each approach. Specifically, I need to understand which option is more cost-effective for my use case (Excel sheet Proprocessing and Generating log files) considering both initial setup and ongoing operational costs ?

@AadhilImam I'm afraid costs can vary a lot based on usage. Try using the pricing calculator  - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/

A further option is to use Azure Batch with a custom activity in ADF, but an HTTP trigger Azure function worked out cheapest for our usecase. With those, you pay per use. With batch pools/Databricks, the baseline cost will be higher because you're paying for the pool/cluster to exist, rather than just when your script is running. But they might work out cheaper if you're needing to run a lot of scripts or you need to pay for a higher tier function, depending on your compute needs.

In terms of development, I use a VSCode devcontainer that replicates the python runtime the function will be deployed to, with the azurite storage emulator so I can test the function locally. Again, cheaper than Databricks for my usecase. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python
